# Is it possible to generate 'random' pixels in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

I want to generate an area of random pixels in Photoshop. By random, I mean the 24-bit RGB values of the pixels vary uniformly over the range `0x000000` - `0xffffff`. The opacity should not vary. I've experimented with the Add Noise filter, but I can't get anything like the desired effect. Is this possible with Photoshop?

Comment: Back in the day you could generate weird pixel images buy going to OPEN RAW > then select a non-image file (like an .exe or something). Not sure if that still works in the later versions.

Comment: Can you explain, in detail, why the noise filter in not appropriate? I want to point out that your definition of "random" (uniform variation) appears to be a unique definition of the term. Also: does "opacity" at a pixel scale have meaning in this context?

Comment: The noise filter is not appropriate because it doesn't do what I've described. Opacity does have a meaning in this context: if pixels are not opaque the distribution will be skewed based on the background colour.

Comment: Can you explain why this is a problem? It sounds like you want arbitrary color data, but then you want it to somehow be influenced by an underlying image. Also, how exactly do you determine "uniform distribution"?

Comment: The [Uniform Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)) is a statistical distribution, that's uniform. I *don't* want it to be influenced by what's underneath, hence the requirement that all the pixels are opaque.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a layer filled with noise from the Add Noise filter, and then make that layer translucent?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I tried stacking Add Noise layers, but it still ended up as a jumble of primary colours.

Comment: In what way is Add Noise failing? Is the distribution not uniform?

Comment: @e100 it is not, at least not uniform across absolute pixel value.

Comment: In what way is it skewed in a histogram?

Comment: How would you handle an area smaller than 4096px square (fewer pixels than colors)?

Comment: @horatio I don't see how that affects this

Comment: ? You said you need the full range of values.

Comment: @horatio Where did I say that? What I want is a Uniform Distribution *over* the full range of values.

Comment: @horatio, uniform distribution just means all outcomes are equally likely, not that the full range of values are returned. With a small sample, you'll get gaps and multiple occurrences of some values; with a large enough sample it'll tend to equal occurrences of each value, i.e. a flat histogram.

Comment: That's fine. He should edit his question with clarifications he made in all the comments. It sounds like the only problem here is that the noise filter requires a background color.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop isn't really meant for this kind of randomness as it is meant for control.

But here's a workaround without any scripting:

1. Select the Pencil Tool
2. Go into the brush options
3. Select 'Color Dynamics'
4. Crank up Foreground/Background Jitter, Hue Jitter, Saturation Jitter, and Brightness Jitter
5. Change the background/foreground color so it isn't just black and white.

This will generate some random values. It won't be 100% random, but you can play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've just used Add Noise, set to "Uniform" in an empty white document and it looks like a uniform distribution to me, with a mean of 127 as expected, when I look at the histogram (after refreshing it). I tried both default (RGB) and monochromatic.

Edits: The histogram shows a peak value at 255 when starting with a white document. I overlooked this -- difficult to see against the right hand edge of the histogram.

Further experimentaion showed:

1. Applying noise to a white canvas gives a peak at 255 only (50% of all pixels)
2. Applying noise to a black canvas gives a peak at 0 only (50% of all pixels)
3. Applying noise to a mid-grey or coloured canvas gives peaks at 0 and 255 (together, 50% of all pixels)

**It seems that Apply Noise returns 50% pixels at low (0) and/or high (255) ends of the range, dependent on the contents of the layer. The remaining 50% pixels appear to be uniformly distributed across the remaining range (0-254, 1-254, or 1-255 depending on input).**

I don't think there is any way of easily fixing this output to give what you're looking for. I think layering clipped multiple versions of (1) and (2) above could reduce the peaks, but not eliminate them entirely. Probably time to roll your own code.

Comment: Don't you get peaks on the histogram at 0 and 255? I certainly did in my experiments.

Comment: Yes, edited answer with more findings.

Answer (score 0):

A 5 second google search found this:

http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=3998

Aside from a PS Script I would say you'd need to use Processing, OpenFrameworks or probably the easiest choice NodeBox.

Comment: If I'm going to have to resort to code I'll just use python/PIL to generate some large images of noise and import them.

Comment: NodeBox is built on Python